# Created a date range for hour and minutes of given datetime

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 or newer

Is there a more concise way to do the following?

Basically, I'm given a `datetime` and I need to create a range based on the hour and minutes.

```
DECLARE @date_in DATETIME = '6/11/2022 7:14:47 PM'

-- Goal is to come up with a date range of the minute
-- In the above example:
-- ...where criteria_date between '6/11/2022 19:14:00' and '6/11/2022 19:15:00'

DECLARE @date_from DATETIME
DECLARE @date_to DATETIME
DECLARE @hourMinutesFrom VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @hourMinutesTo VARCHAR(5)

SELECT @hourMinutesFrom = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@date_in,108) 
SELECT @hourMinutesTo = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(MINUTE,1,@date_in),108) 

SELECT @date_from = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @date_in), @hourMinutesFrom)
SELECT @date_to = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @date_in), @hourMinutesTo)

SELECT @date_from
SELECT @date_to
```

Comment: To confirm, do you really want values where `criteria_date`  is `>= '2022-11-06T19:14'` and `< '2022-11-06T19:15'`? So would include `'2022-11-06T19:14:47'` and `'2022-11-06T19:15:00'` but *not* `'2022-11-06T19:15:01'` (so a total range of 61 seconds)?

Comment: yes, seems easier than trying to get 19:14:59. ?

Comment: I'm not sure what "ease" has to do with it. `BETWEEN` here would give you from `2022-11-06T19:14:00.0000000` to `2022-11-06T19:15:00.0000000` *inclusive*. Excluding the `2022-11-06T19:14:00.0000000` is simple, just don't use `BETWEEN` and use `>=` and `<` logic; hence why my question on is it's intended to include `2022-11-06T19:14:00.0000000`.

Comment: yes, where criteria_date is >= '2022-11-06T19:14' and < '2022-11-06T19:15'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2022 (which is in preview), you could use `DATE_BUCKET`:

```sql
DECLARE @date datetime = '2022-11-06T19:14:47'; --Don't use ambiguous date formats

SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE criteria_date BETWEEN DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE,1,@date) AND DATEADD(MINUTE,1,DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE,1,@date));
```

Note that due to your use of `BETWEEN` this will include `'2022-11-06T19:15:00'` but *not* `'2022-11-06T19:15:01'`.

On older version, then you would need to use "messier" `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` logic and "magic" dates:

```sql
DECLARE @date datetime = '2022-11-06T19:14:47'; --Don't use ambiguous date formats

SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE criteria_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @Date),0) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @Date)+1, 0);
```

If you don't want exactly `'2022-11-06T19:15:00'` then use `>=` and `<` logic rather than `BETWEEN`. `DATE_BUCKET` is also sort preserving, so you you may find the following is SARGable too (I don't have a 2022 instance at home yet to test this, due to lack of the Linux release):

```sql
DECLARE @date datetime = '2022-11-06T19:14:47'; --Don't use ambiguous date formats

SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE,1,criteria_date) = DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE,1,@date);
```